# Прозрачный фон в ScrollView

Tags: android, background, android-scrollview

Добрый день, Подскажите как сделать прозрачным фон в ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:background="#14ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_about_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="@string/about_text" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

`android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"`
Примените эту тему к своей активности.

Comment: Если вы хотите изменить основной фон, то нужно копать в сторону стилей.

Comment: Фон не изменился а вот текст пропал, буду копать

Comment: Совет все таки оказался правильным, совсем забыл что у меня этот ScrollView в Манифесте прописан в теме Dialog